# Anyone using Archipel in production for managing virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization, openvz, xmpp

I am getting ready to deploy a new server for my company.  We intend to use virtualization mainly for security but also to help with versioning and other issues.  We have decided to use openvz.  Now I am trying to pick out some management software to make it easier to monitor, deploy, and migrate instances.  There are commercial solutions such as SolusVM, but we are much more comfortable with open source software.  Archipel looks like a promising solution, albeit a bit strange considering the use of XMPP.  Has anyone used this in production?  Would you suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

im evaluating this, and found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/archipelproject/6HOBLF2aFtg
it looks like archipel seems to support openvz via libvirt, but is mainly tailored for qemu/kvm/..
i'll post again, if i can make my setup work.